# How to serve file under root path using Nginx?

Tags: nginx, static-files

I have a website laike9m.com, which is served by Nginx. I want to access a text file `AAA.txt` with url `laike9m.com/AAA.txt`. The text file is on my server, let's say it's `$HOME/AAA.txt`. Redirection is not allowed. Current Nginx conf file is [here](https://github.com/laike9m/media/blob/master/Nginx/nginx.conf). Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
location ~ ^(.*\.txt)$ {
    alias /home/laike9m/$1;
}
```

Solved it.